# Error al intentar iniciar sesion con los servicios de federación de active directory: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, windows-server, adfs

Estoy intentando implementar los servicios de federación de active directory (ADFS) en mi aplicación asp.net core mvc, para ello ya tengo instalados y configurados (supongo que bien) el controlador de dominio (DC) el IIS y el mismo servicio de ADFS todos funcionando.

Posteriormente agrego la siguiente configuración (tomada en la web de Microsoft) en el program.cs de mi aplicación.

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddWsFederation(options =>
{
    // MetadataAddress represents the Active Directory instance used to authenticate users.
    options.MetadataAddress = "https://adfs.labmait.local/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml";

    options.Wtrealm = "https://localhost:44323/";

    //options.Wtrealm = "api://bbd35166-7c13-49f3-8041-9551f2847b69";

});
```

La aplicación se ejecuta correctamente, pero al intentar iniciar sesión con el servicio de federación de active directory (ADFS) me lanza estas excepciones.

```
SocketException: Host desconocido.
    System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpRequestException: Host desconocido. (adfs.labmait.local:443)
    System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(string host, int port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancel)
InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<T>.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel).
```

Ya llevo tiempo intentando dar con la solución, pero hasta ahora no lo consigo.

Soy muy nuevo en eso, apenas es la primera vez que estoy intentando implementar el servicio de ADFS en una aplicación asp.net core MVC.
GRACIAS ANTICIPADAS!

Comment: Parece que no tienes acceso a "https://adfs.labmait.local/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" Prueba a ver si con un navegador puedes acceder primero.